# i18n Internationalization and Localization in React Django

Tags: django, reactjs, internationalization, django-i18n

I am working on a Project where I am using React js for Front-End and Django for backend. I need to implement **i18n Internationalization and Localization**
I saw Django documentation and came across django I18n javascript_catalog. 
How to use the same using getText() in React JS?. Is there any other way to implement?.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

**Update for: django > 2.0**:

```py
from django.views.i18n import JavaScriptCatalog

urlpatterns = [
    path('jsi18n/', JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(), name='javascript-catalog'),
]
```

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#module-django.views.i18n)

**Old**:

Use below code in `urls.py` of project

```
from django.views.i18n import javascript_catalog
js_info_dict = {
    'domain': 'djangojs',
    'packages': ('name',)
}


urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^jsi18n/$', javascript_catalog, js_info_dict),
```

Add below line to your base html file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jsi18n/"></script>
```